# Why didn't this answer appear in the late answers queue?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, late-answers

As I write this, my late answers queue shows 0 posts.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29776115/1768232) is basically code only, and is flat out wrong. I only saw it because I have the RSS feed up for the [gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson) tag. It doesn't show up in the 10k tools either:

[image: 10k tools screenshot]

I know the user has over 300 rep, but I think it still should have made it into the queue. Is 330 rep enough to avoid the queue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is. If you look at the description for the queue:

> Review late answers **from new users**

A new user is defined as someone with less than 10 reputation.

Comment: Ah, I knew it was a low reputation threshold but not that low. Thanks!